# web3.py provider error -- 'Web3' has no 'eth' member

Tags: solidity, web3.py

Hi I am trying to use web3.py to connect some python code to a solidity contract and I am getting an error -- Web3 instance has no eth member.

```
    w3 = Web3(EthereumTesterProvider())

contract_source_path = r'\tournament.sol'
compiled_sol = compile_source_file(contract_source_path)

contract_id, contract_interface = compiled_sol.popitem()

address = deploy_contract(w3, contract_interface)
print("Deployed {0} to: {1}\n".format(contract_id, address))

tournament_contract = w3.eth.contract(
    address = address,
    abi=contract_interface['abi']
)
```

I am not sure why this is happening as the w3 variable holds Web3(EthereumTesterProvider()) which should have an eth member object.

Comment: Did you import [the newer EthereumTesterProvider or the legacy version](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#ethereumtesterprovider)? Have you tried using the [automatic provider](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#automatic-vs-manual-providers) without EthereumTesterProvider?

Comment: i did use the newer EthereumTestererProvider and i just tried using automatic provider by itself but that says w3 is not callable.

Comment: how do you use w3 auto. would it look like...

`code`tournament_contract = w3().eth.contract(...)

this produces error: w3 is not callable

Comment: For auto I'm just talking about using ["w3 = Web3()" or equivalently "from web3.auto import w3"](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/providers.html#automatic-vs-manual-providers). I think you would still use "w3.eth.contract(...)". I don't know if this would work, but it seems worth testing (especially since the docs describe EthereumTesterProvider as experimental or deprecated depending on version).

Comment: yes i have tried it this way. i am not sure why it is producing this error. it seems that it shouldnt be.

currently i have this
`code`"w3 = Web3()

contract_source_path = r'\tournament.sol'
compiled_sol = compile_source_file(contract_source_path)

contract_id, contract_interface = compiled_sol.popitem()

address = deploy_contract(w3, contract_interface)
print("Deployed {0} to: {1}\n".format(contract_id, address))

tournament_contract = w3.eth.contract(
    address = address,
    abi=contract_interface['abi']
)"
and get this "E1101:Instance of 'Web3' has no 'eth' member

Comment: even just this produces the same error   `code`from web3 import Web3

w3 = Web3()

w3.eth.contract()

Comment: Are you running a local node with geth, parity, etc.? Maybe you need to run a local node separately and connect to it [as described here](http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#connecting-to-your-node). I usually use [ganache](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache-cli) for testing but I haven't tried it with web3.py.

Comment: no i am not so that is a good idea. thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Why not just use Infura?

```
linkUrl = 'https://mainnet.infura.io/your_secret_code'
w3 = Web3(HTTPProvider(linkUrl))
from web3.middleware import geth_poa_middleware
# inject the poa compatibility middleware to the innermost layer
w3.middleware_stack.inject(geth_poa_middleware, layer=0)
print("w3.version.node: " + w3.version.node)
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and as a beginner too, I am not 100% sure if I got it right.
I guess you'd would have figured out after 7 months so I'm trying to get some help here.

So, just as far as how understood it is that those sub classes of Web3 class like personal, eth and so on are modules which will be attached to Web3 class in runtime so it will work fine after linking to the Etherium server provider.
I ran into the same warnings using Visual Code and when I just run it directly on bash with

```
python app_name.py
```

and it works fine so far.